# Doctrine2 Gedmo sluggable behavior, change the separator to "+"

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine-orm, behavior

I'm trying to change the default separator to "+"

```
/**
 * @var string $slug
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"label"}, separator="+")
 * @ORM\Column(length=130, unique=true)
 * @Expose
 */
protected $slug;
```

It doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]
Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 24
```

When trying to escape the "+" with "\+", I don't have this error any-more but in the database I've got the following:

```
my\+slug
```

Same thing with a double escape "\\". Any idea?

Comment: Have reported this on github?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1240

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty-hack, when desactiving the unique constraint the bug doesn't happen.

```
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"label"}, separator="+", unique=false)
```